# Edit PSD smart object programmatically

Tags: javascript, photoshop, psd

There is PSDfile which makes lanyard with one base image( https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nlpnwx4771uwoe/Lanyard_Mockup_1.psd?dl=0 ). I want to edit the base image with psd.js tool. If we open PSD document in photoshop and edit smart object, then whole lanyard design changes. Can anyone help me with solution

I get following JSON after export of psd object.

```
 {
    "children": [
    {
      "type": "layer",
      "visible": true,
      "opacity": 0,
      "blendingMode": "normal",
      "name": "Lanyard project",
      "left": -1054,
      "right": 0,
      "top": -153,
      "bottom": 45,
      "height": 198,
      "width": 1054,
      "mask": {},
      "image": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "group",
      "visible": true,
      "opacity": 1,
      "blendingMode": "normal",
      "name": "Mockup",
      "left": -441,
      "right": 2637,
      "top": 0,
      "bottom": 1000,
      "height": 1000,
      "width": 3078,
      "children": [
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "normal",
          "name": "Highlights",
          "left": 0,
          "right": 2500,
          "top": 0,
          "bottom": 1000,
          "height": 1000,
          "width": 2500,
          "mask": {
            "top": 396,
            "left": 270,
            "bottom": 664,
            "right": 2448,
            "width": 2178,
            "height": 268,
            "defaultColor": 0,
            "relative": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "invert": false
          },
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
          "name": "LANYARD MOCKUP copy 5",
          "left": 1412,
          "right": 2395,
          "top": 382,
          "bottom": 571,
          "height": 189,
          "width": 983,
          "mask": {
            "top": 454,
            "left": 1324,
            "bottom": 726,
            "right": 2393,
            "width": 1069,
            "height": 272,
            "defaultColor": 255,
            "relative": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "invert": false
          },
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
          "name": "LANYARD MOCKUP copy 9",
          "left": -441,
          "right": 382,
          "top": 461,
          "bottom": 648,
          "height": 187,
          "width": 823,
          "mask": {
            "top": 455,
            "left": 269,
            "bottom": 625,
            "right": 389,
            "width": 120,
            "height": 170,
            "defaultColor": 0,
            "relative": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "invert": false
          },
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
          "name": "LANYARD MOCKUP copy 4",
          "left": 364,
          "right": 1418,
          "top": 417,
          "bottom": 612,
          "height": 195,
          "width": 1054,
          "mask": {},
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
          "name": "LANYARD MOCKUP copy 8",
          "left": 2035,
          "right": 2448,
          "top": 186,
          "bottom": 852,
          "height": 666,
          "width": 413,
          "mask": {
            "top": 451,
            "left": 2307,
            "bottom": 599,
            "right": 2465,
            "width": 158,
            "height": 148,
            "defaultColor": 0,
            "relative": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "invert": false
          },
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
          "name": "LANYARD MOCKUP copy 7",
          "left": 1633,
          "right": 2637,
          "top": 519,
          "bottom": 666,
          "height": 147,
          "width": 1004,
          "mask": {
            "top": 511,
            "left": 1630,
            "bottom": 725,
            "right": 2500,
            "width": 870,
            "height": 214,
            "defaultColor": 0,
            "relative": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "invert": false
          },
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
          "name": "LANYARD MOCKUP copy 6",
          "left": 487,
          "right": 1645,
          "top": 464,
          "bottom": 650,
          "height": 186,
          "width": 1158,
          "mask": {
            "top": 461,
            "left": 484,
            "bottom": 653,
            "right": 1646,
            "width": 1162,
            "height": 192,
            "defaultColor": 0,
            "relative": false,
            "disabled": false,
            "invert": false
          },
          "image": {}
        },
        {
          "type": "layer",
          "visible": true,
          "opacity": 1,
          "blendingMode": "normal",
          "name": "Levels 1",
          "left": 56,
          "right": 2449,
          "top": 395,
          "bottom": 666,
          "height": 271,
          "width": 2393,
          "mask": {},
          "image": {}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "layer",
      "visible": true,
      "opacity": 1,
      "blendingMode": "linear_burn",
      "name": "Shadow",
      "left": 0,
      "right": 2500,
      "top": 0,
      "bottom": 1000,
      "height": 1000,
      "width": 2500,
      "mask": {
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "bottom": 1000,
        "right": 2500,
        "width": 2500,
        "height": 1000,
        "defaultColor": 255,
        "relative": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "invert": false
      },
      "image": {}
    },
    {
      "type": "layer",
      "visible": true,
      "opacity": 1,
      "blendingMode": "normal",
      "name": "Background color",
      "left": 0,
      "right": 2500,
      "top": 0,
      "bottom": 1000,
      "height": 1000,
      "width": 2500,
      "mask": {
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "bottom": 0,
        "right": 0,
        "width": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "defaultColor": 255,
        "relative": false,
        "disabled": false,
        "invert": false
      },
      "image": {}
    }
    ],
    "document": {
    "width": 2500,
    "height": 1000,
    "resources": {
      "layerComps": [],
      "guides": [],
      "slices": []
    }
   }
```

Comment: PSD.js is a file parser, what do you mean you want to edit your image with it? What exactly you want to do? What's the expected result? It's unclear what you want

Comment: Sergey kritskiy thanks for reply. If you open the psd document in Photoshop and edit layer 1 image you can see that whole lanyard gets changed. I am making an application in which user can upload a psd mockup and a base image. The application will return lanyard image by combining base image and mockup. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fkojc6xaqxleh02/lanyard.mp4?dl=0 here is video of problem

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what's the problem. In the video everything works as it should: there's a hidden smart object, you edit it, then all its transformed copies are updated. If your question is how to make the same functionality in a web app, then I don't know, sorry, maybe someone more experienced will be able to help: this spunds like a very complex task

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Thanks for reply
 Yes I want to implement this functionality as a web app. Where users can upload base image(Smart object being edited in video) and get the finished image of lanyard. In PSD.js  was able to extract individual components of lanyard but stuck on editing part. Anyways will wait for someone else to guide me. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Harvi, I have same problem. Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score -2):

PSD.js is for only Read file. we can Edit PSD using PSD.jS. Hopefully this comment help for other